# NiFi & Spark Integration Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/protocol/HttpAsyncResponseConsumer

Tags: spark-streaming, classnotfoundexception, apache-nifi

I am trying to setup a very basic example.

1. Push random data to Output port in NiFi
2. Use Spark streaming context to print received data.

Versions (All on single instance)

> 1. HDF - 3.1.1.0-35
> 2. HDP - 2.6.5.0-292
> 3. nifi-spark-receiver & site-to-site-client - 1.7.1

I have configured spark-defaults.conf as follows

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /usr/hdf/3.1.1.0-35/nifi/work/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-client-dto-1.5.0.3.1.1.0-35.jar:/opt/spark-receiver/httpcore-nio-4.0-alpha6.jar:/opt/spark-receiver/nifi-site-to-site-client-1.5.0.3.1.2.0-7.jar:/opt/spark-receiver/nifi-spark-receiver-1.5.0.3.1.2.0-7.jar:/usr/hdf/3.1.1.0-35/nifi/lib/nifi-api-1.5.0.3.1.1.0-35.jar:/usr/hdf/3.1.1.0-35/nifi/lib/bootstrap/nifi-utils-1.5.0.3.1.1.0-35.jar:/usr/hdf/3.1.1.0-35/nifi/lib/nifi-framework-api-1.5.0.3.1.1.0-35.jar
```

I am running following commands in spark-shell

```
import org.apache.nifi._ 
import java.nio.charset._ 
import org.apache.nifi.spark._ 
import org.apache.nifi.remote.client._ 
import org.apache.spark._ 
import org.apache.nifi.events._ 
import org.apache.spark.streaming._ 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 
import org.apache.nifi.remote._ 
import org.apache.nifi.remote.client._ 
import org.apache.nifi.remote.protocol._ 
import org.apache.spark.storage._ 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver._ 
import java.io._ 
import org.apache.spark.serializer._ 

val conf = new SiteToSiteClient.Builder().url("http://10.140.0.2:9090/nifi").portName("toSpark").buildConfig()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val lines = ssc.receiverStream(new NiFiReceiver(conf, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY))
val text = lines.map(dataPacket => new String(dataPacket.getContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
text.print()
ssc.start()
```

After running this code, I get following error:

> Exception in thread "NiFi Receiver" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/nio/protocol/HttpAsyncResponseConsumer
>           at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.SiteInfoProvider.createSiteToSiteRestApiClient(SiteInfoProvider.java:104)
>           at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.SiteInfoProvider.refreshRemoteInfo(SiteInfoProvider.java:68)
>           at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.SiteInfoProvider.getPortIdentifier(SiteInfoProvider.java:220)
>           at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.SiteInfoProvider.getOutputPortIdentifier(SiteInfoProvider.java:204)
>           at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.socket.SocketClient.getPortIdentifier(SocketClient.java:79)
>           at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.socket.SocketClient.createTransaction(SocketClient.java:121)
>           at org.apache.nifi.spark.NiFiReceiver$ReceiveRunnable.run(NiFiReceiver.java:149)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncResponseConsumer
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your inclusion of httpcore-nio-4.0-alpha6.jar is the issue, as that version doesn't have that class in it, which appears to be interfering with the version of httpcore-nio that is included transitively with the nifi-spark-receiver (currently version 4.4.6).

Comment: Initially I tried without it and it was still not working. It was giving same error.

Comment: Maybe explicitly add the 4.4.6 version as you had with the 4.0.6a version?

Comment: tried it...but no luck. On the other hand, I was able to run this sample using spark-submit (sbt uber jar)...though had to remove explicit dependencies defined in spark-defaults.conf..